# C# XML. Get data from XML to object, update in UI, save back to XML

Tags: c#, xml

let me describe the situation. Winforms C#
I have xml file with data. I load this data to an user defined class object using `Deserialize`.
Based on this object with data, I build [in Form] UI: many `tabPages` of custom controls (textBox, 2 buttons in groupBox). I can also save this user defined class object using `Serialize` to XML file. 

**Question:**
When I update `textBox.Text` in Form UI in custom control I do not know how to keep connection with the object with data (Layout layout) and save the updated object with data to XML. The change of text happens only in user custom control TextBox. I want to update data from UI in data object (layout) and then simply save with `Serialization`.

user class:

```
public class Layout
{
    public string type;
    public List<TabPage> TabPageList;
    public Layout()
    {
        this.TabPageList = new List<TabPage>();
    }
}
public class TabPage
{
    public string text;
    public List<ActionGroup> ActionGroupList;

    public TabPage()
    {
        this.ActionGroupList = new List<ActionGroup>();
    }
}
public class ActionGroup
{
    public string type;
    public string text;
    public string sourceLocal;
    public string sourceRemote;

    public ActionGroup()
    {
        this.type = string.Empty;
        this.text = string.Empty;
        this.sourceLocal = string.Empty;
        this.sourceRemote = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Custom control:

```
public partial class ViewActionGroup : UserControl
{
    public string type;
    public string text;
    public string sourceLocal;
    public string sourceRemote;
    public bool isRemote;
    public bool isDone;

    public ViewActionGroup()
    {
        this.type = string.Empty;
        this.text = string.Empty;
        this.sourceLocal = string.Empty;
        this.sourceRemote = string.Empty;
        this.isRemote = false;
        this.isDone = false;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public ViewActionGroup(ActionGroup actionGroup)
    {
        this.type = actionGroup.type;
        this.text = actionGroup.text;
        this.sourceLocal = actionGroup.sourceLocal;
        this.sourceRemote = actionGroup.sourceRemote;
        this.isRemote = false;
        this.isDone = false;
        InitializeComponent();

        groupBox1.Text = text;
        button1.Text = type;
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
        textBox1.Text = sourceLocal;
        textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    }

    public void ChangeToRemote()
    {
        isRemote = true;
        textBox1.Text = this.sourceRemote;            
    }

    public void ChangeToLocal()
    {
        isRemote = false;
        textBox1.Text = this.sourceLocal;            
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.isRemote)
        {
            this.sourceRemote = textBox1.Text;
        }
        else 
        {
            this.sourceLocal = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Creating UI where I loose connection between UI and data object:

```
    private void CreateLayout(Layout layout)
    {
        this.Text = layout.type;
        TabControl tabControl = new TabControl();

        tabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        int tabCount = 0;

        foreach (TabPage tabpage in layout.TabPageList)
        {
            int actionCount = 0;

            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabpage.text);
            foreach (ActionGroup actionGroup in tabpage.ActionGroupList)
            {
                ViewActionGroup view = new ViewActionGroup(actionGroup);
                view.Location = new Point(0, actionCount * view.Height);
                tabControl.TabPages[tabCount].Controls.Add(view);
                tabControl.TabPages[tabCount].AutoScroll = true;
                tabControl.TabPages[tabCount].AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(tabControl.Width/2,tabControl.Height);
                actionCount++;
            }
            tabCount++;
            this.panelMain.Controls.Add(tabControl);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this wpf or winforms?

Comment: @loopedcode This is Winforms C#

Comment: Hi Lukasz, Please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. It would be very kind of you to vote helpful answers up and - if an answer helped you to solve your problem - you should mark it as the accepted answer, This will show to others, that this question is solved. If the answer is not helpfull please place a comment,Thx!

Comment: I am going to check it this weekend. Had no time, sorry. I will come back and comment. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common ways:

One is a routine `WriteDataIntoControls` and another `ReadDataFromControls` where you transfer the data to and from your visible controls manually (advantage: highest degree of control). In this case you'd have to read your object from your XML source, deserialize it into your business object and create all visible controls together with their value. On saving you'd have to transfer all values into your business object and serizalize it after this.

The second is DataBinding (advantage: highest degree of automation). Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You can bind to simple values as well as to lists (including navigation) or complex objects.

You find a tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Comment: Icannot format here. I have a question. I have sth like this: 
    view.DataBindings.Add("SourceLocal", actionGroup, "SourceLocal", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
                    view.DataBindings.Add("SourceRemote", actionGroup, "SourceRemote", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

How bind two fields from object to two fields from custom control?

Comment: @Lukasz, You can add two DataBindings... Please to not ask follow-up questions in comments. They do not pull any attention... Rather start a new question, where you can format and describe in detail...

Answer (score 1):

@Shnugo Thank You for your feedback. The tutorial you posted did not help because it is too hard for me but Data Binding topic gave me some clue.

Here easy tutorial in VB actually but simple. It helped me to do it quickly in C#.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqLQ2K9YY2A

C# solution

```
class MyObject
{
    string name;

    public MyObject()
    { }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name;}
        set { name = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj.Name = "Lucas";
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", obj, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = obj.Name;
    }
}
```